# Raspberry loose Bluetooth connection after a few seconds

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

My Raspberry PI3 looses the Built-In Bluetooth connection after a few seconds.

I´m using it with Gigaset G-Tags but it is not stable. Does anyone have an idea? I did update & upgrade. The distance of the G-Tags is just 3-5m.

I want to use it as a presence control. Does anyone have an idea what i could try?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: Increase your slave latency. Maybe the transmission power of the signal is low or the interference from other sources (WLAN?) is high, so that many packets are lost. By increasing the slave latency, you increase the tolerance for lost packets, because it allows for a longer time without an answer from the slave. However, it might be that the slave just gets lazier and things won't change much. But it is worth a try.

Comment: Do you have an example how to do it? I’m a newbe on raspberry

Comment: I don't know much about the concrete specifics either. Slave Latency is part of the connection parameters. I don't know if your Built-in Bluetooth allows you to set the connection parameters explicitly. Check for options to set these parameters, maybe it is possible.